# The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error is resolved

Tags: python, sendgrid

I follow this link:

https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/sender-verification

In my sendgrid account the from_email is set as verifie Single sender authentication, but when i send email verifications in my localhost, i still receive the same message : **The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity**

my config:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your api generate password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: Isn't it better to ask this question to Sendgrid support?

Comment: I wish the support would respond here too, when you look for an answer stackoverflow is very useful so it can help other  for same question

Comment: Did you get an answer? :-) @Lifechess
Please share if you did. Thanks

Comment: yes , i have to add my domain at the end the from email ex: no-reply@mydomaine.com to match my domain in sendgrid, but there could be other issue that give the same problem.

Comment: It would be super fucking nice if this question was answered anywhere by sendgrid - it could go on the "getting started with SMTP" page, or the troubleshooting SMTP page, or on a brand new page, or literally anywhere. I would tell them that directly if I could figure out how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add another line to your config containing the verified sender's address:

`DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'you@domain.com'`